# What are default modules in python (which are imported when we run Python as for example "print")

Tags: python, printing

What are the default modules in Python which are automatically imported when Python compiler is launched?

These are, for example, `print`, addition, and other mathematical functions.
They must be defined somewhere in Python

I had guessed that we can extract this information by finding (for example from where `print` function has come from if we know this information we can get the module it has come from).

Comment: The fundamentals of Python are implemented in C inside your `/usr/bin/python`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"module" has a particular meaning in Python. Neither "print" nor "addition" is a module.

`+` and the other "mathematical functions" are ***operators***, while `for`, `in`, `if`, etc. are ***keywords***, not functions, and so aren't going to be in `__builtins__`.

If you actually want to know what ***modules*** are loaded when you start Python, look at `sys.modules.keys()`:

```
$ python -i
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules.keys()
['copy_reg', 'sre_compile', 'locale', '_sre', 'functools', 'encodings', 'site',
'__builtin__', 'sysconfig', 'operator', '__main__', 'types', 'encodings.encodings',
'abc', '_weakrefset', 'errno', 'encodings.codecs', 'sre_constants', 're', '_abcoll',
'ntpath', '_codecs', 'nt', '_warnings', 'genericpath', 'stat', 'zipimport',
'encodings.__builtin__', 'warnings', 'UserDict', 'encodings.cp1252', 'sys',
'codecs', 'os.path', '_functools', '_locale', 'signal', 'traceback', 'linecache',
'encodings.aliases', 'exceptions', 'sre_parse', 'os', '_weakref']
```

Comment: `idlelib` will be not listed using `sys.modules.keys(), but is available for import at Python prompt and listed in Python documentation https://docs.python.org/3.10/py-modindex.html .

Answer (score 6):

All these functions are part of module `__builtins__`.  Fire up a python shell and check the help -

```
>>> help(__builtins__)
```

Comment: `__builtins__` is a module, not a dict so it doesn't have `keys()` method. `dir(__builtins__)` should give a list of items that are imported automatically (not considering __doc__, __name__ etc).

Comment: thanks for the answer but are they any more like __builtin__ which are imported automatically

and one more thing can we find name of module by just having the function names 

just in case if we dont know which module is importing it

Comment: Some of them are built into the language, and therefore aren't really anywhere, unless you count some C code that is used to implement Python... and even then, even if you understand the code, it is hard to point to a part of it and say "this is XYZ Python functionality".

Comment: @EliBendersky RonakG is right, that `help` is correct. However, if you're actually looking for which ___modules___ are imported when you run Python, those are _not_ listed in `__builtins__` so if it's an interview question that's the wrong answer.

Comment: @agf so then whats the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Python has three scopes:

- local
- global
- builtin

If you're executing the following function:

```
def foo():
    print('bar')
```

Python looks the for the `print` function it in these scopes top-to-bottom. First it checks if there is a local variable in `foo` named `print`. Then, if that fails, if `print` is a global script/module object (in this example `foo` function is such an object). If that fails as well, it looks in the `__builtin__` module.

The `__builtin__` module is where all functions like `print` are defined. It also contains builtin exception classes.

Addition and other operators are different because they work on objects. Every object has a type, for example an integer `123` is of type `int`. The `int` type defines how two integers can be added and what is the result.

In `CPython` (Python from python.org), the `__builtin__` module and all basic types (`int`, `str`, `list`, etc.) are written in C and are part of the core (the `python` executable file). There are other modules that are written the same way, most notably the `sys` module. You won't find `sys.py` in Python's standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The `__builtins__` module contains the `print` function, as well as many other functions and classes.  In a shell, `help(__builtins__)` will give you an almost absurdly-detailed list of functions, classes, and those classes functions.  Using `dir(__builtins__)` may be more useful, as it simply returns a list of the names of the included functions and classes.

Comment: However that has nothing to do with what _modules_ are loaded, nor does it cover "addition".

Answer (score 0):

__ **builtin** __ is imported by default on all program run.

type, str, dir, and all the rest of Python's built-in functions are grouped into a special module called __ **builtin** __ . (That's two underscores before and after.) If it helps, you can think of Python automatically executing from __ **builtin** __ import * on startup, which imports all the “built-in” functions into the namespace so you can use them directly.

The advantage of thinking like this is that you can access all the built-in functions and attributes as a group by getting information about the **builtin** module. And guess what, Python has a function called info. Try it yourself and skim through the list now. We'll dive into some of the more important functions later. (Some of the built-in error classes, like AttributeError, should already look familiar.)

Source and reference : [DiveIntoPython](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/built_in_functions.html#d0e8958)

Answer (score 0):

To see all the installed modules you can use the following command in python interpreter.`help("modules")`. It will show all the installed modules.If you are looking for inbuilt functions like `print` use the command `help(__builtins__)` in python shell.